# Having troubles with pagination on swift collectionView

Tags: swift, pagination, uicollectionview

My goal is load more info when the user reaches the end of my collectionViewPokemon, but the `getPokes` func I'm using to achieve this is being called X amount of times, corresponding to the while statement I implemented to get the info from other endpoints. That's far from the behavior I expected.

This is how my code looks:

**Service class**

```
class Service {

let baseUrl = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon"
let limit = 20
var offset = 0
var isPaginating = false

func getPokes(pagination: Bool = false,
              handler: @escaping ([Pokemon]) -> Void) {
    
    let topCalls = (limit*5)-limit
    
    let originalPokes = [Pokemon]()
    let morePokemons = [Pokemon]()
    var endpoint = "\(baseUrl)/?limit=\(limit)&offset=\(offset)"
    
    if pagination {
        while offset < topCalls {
                isPaginating = true
                offset += limit
            
            endpoint = "\(baseUrl)/?limit=\(limit)&offset=\(offset)"
            
            self.mainApiCall(mainList: morePokemons, endpoint: endpoint) { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let pokemons):
                    handler(pokemons)
                    
                    if pagination {
                        self.isPaginating = true
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        self.mainApiCall(mainList: originalPokes, endpoint: endpoint) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let pokemons):
                handler(pokemons)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewController class** (the properties)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,
                  UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,
                  UICollectionViewDelegate,
                  UICollectionViewDataSource,
                  UIScrollViewDelegate {

private let service = Service()
private var pagingChecker = false

var generalList = [Pokemon]()
var pokemons = [Pokemon]()
var morePokemons = [Pokemon]()

    . . .
}
```

**viewDidLoad method** (this is ok so far)

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    setViews()
    service.getPokes(pagination: false) { [self] (pokes) in
        
        pokemons = pokes
        generalList += pokemons
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            collectionViewPokemon?.reloadData()
        }
        
    }
}
```

**scrollViewDidScroll method** (here's the error)

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let position = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if position > ((collectionViewPokemon!.contentSize.height) - 200 - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
        
        guard !service.isPaginating else { return }
        
        if !pagingChecker {
            service.getPokes(pagination: true) { [self] (morePokes) in
                
                morePokemons = morePokes
                generalList += morePokemons
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    collectionViewPokemon?.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } else {
            pagingChecker = true
            print("Done paging.")
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is I wanna fetch just one array of pokemons at a time, but instead I'm making all the endpoint calls at the same time, and also appending them to my generalList array, who owns my collectionView datasource and all that stuff.

**PD:** Idk if it'll help, but here's a screenshot of my console. The first msg is ok, but it should print the others only when the user reaches the end of the CollectionView, and well, that's not happening (instead, they're all coming back at the same time!)

[image: Screenshot]

I can't figure out how to get this done. I would really appreciate any advice or correction, thanks.

Comment: Where does a guy named topCalls come from?

Comment: I get 20 pokemons per call (that's the limit property), so, I work with just 100 pokemons (and make just 5 calls). The topCalls just stores that calculation, so the while statement runs until it reaches the desired number of pokemons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was happening. I was using a while statement to repeat my Api call as long as it satisfy it's condition (limit<topCalls).

So, I worked out some ways to not using that while statement, and ended up using a function to construct every URL, and then, set up a shouldPage parameter that checked if that apiCall needed to be done or not.

This is how my code ended up:

```
let baseUrl = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon"
let limit = 20
var offset = 0

func getPokes(pageNumber: Int = 1,
              shouldPage: Bool = true,
              handler: @escaping ([Pokemon]) -> Void) {
    
    let originalPokes = [Pokemon]()
    let morePokemons = [Pokemon]()
    let endpoint = buildEndpoint(shouldPage: shouldPage)
    
    if  shouldPage {
            
            mainApiCall(mainList: morePokemons, endpoint: endpoint) { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let pokemons):
                    handler(pokemons)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
    } else {
        mainApiCall(mainList: originalPokes, endpoint: endpoint) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let pokemons):
                handler(pokemons)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

private func buildEndpoint(shouldPage: Bool = false) -> String {
    
    var endpoint = "\(baseUrl)/?limit=\(limit)&offset=\(offset)"
    
    if shouldPage {
        offset += limit
        endpoint = "\(baseUrl)/?limit=\(limit)&offset=\(offset)"
    }
    
    return endpoint
}
```

That's on my Service class. So, in my CollectionView Datasource, I call getPokes(shouldPage: false) on cellForItemAt, and in willDisplay cell I say shouldPage is true. That fixed the problem.